# Symfony Cache Component (3.1) not saving cache

Tags: php, caching, symfony-3.1

I'm using the new Symfony Cache Component. I generate my cache first with a command (Command/AppCacheGenerateCommand.php):

```
$cache = new FilesystemAdapter();         
foreach ($domains as $domain){
        if ($domain->getHost()){
            $output->writeln('Generate cache for domain: ' . $domain->getHost());
            $domainCache = $cache->getItem('domain.' . $domain->getHost());
            $domainCache->set($domain->getId());
            $cache->save($domainCache);
        }
    }
```

Then trying to get these cached elements in a onKernelRequest EventListener (EventListener/RequestListener.php)

```
$cache = new FileSystemAdapter();
    $domainCache = $cache->getItem('domain.' . $host);
    if (!$domainCache->isHit()){
        die;
    }
```

It's always dies here, not going further. Anyone can give me an explanation? (I've tried if the host not matching, but it does...)

Comment: You have to add an answer with the solution (and then accept it) and NOT as update inside your question. Take a look at the Help Center!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out the answer:

First I had to add cache config in config.yml:

```
framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            my_cache_name:
                adapter: cache.adapter.filesystem
                default_lifetime: 0
```

Than instead of

```
$cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
```

I had to use the new service like:

```
$cache = $this->getContainer()->get('my_cache_name);
```

And it's started working! Hope it helps to others!

Comment: You have to add the answer here and NOT as update inside your question. Take a look at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section or at the thousand of questions with an accepted Answer here on StackOverflow to got it.

Comment: Please take note of @gp_sflover's advice. Use answers for answers and questions for questions. It's as simple as that. I've done it now for you, But save others time, the next time. Cheers